# less than 10 add 0 to number

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

How can I modify this code to add a 0 before any digits lower than 10

```
$('#detect').html( toGeo(apX, screenX)  + latT +', '+ toGeo(apY, screenY) + lonT  );

function toGeo(d, max) {
   var c = '';

   var r = d/max * 180;
   var deg = Math.floor(r);
   c += deg + "° ";

   r = (r - deg) * 60;
   var min = Math.floor(r);
   c += min + "′ ";

   r = (r - min) * 60;
   var sec = Math.floor(r);
   c += sec + "″";

   return c;
}
```

So the outpout would change from

4° 7′ 34″W, 168° 1′ 23″N

to

04° 07′ 34″W, 168° 01′ 23″N

Thanks for your time

Comment: Dup: [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1267283/90527), [JavaScript, Regex, add leading zero to ALL number contained in string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9812610/90527), and many others.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

You can always do

```
('0' + deg).slice(-2)
```

See [`slice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp):

> You can also use negative numbers to select from the end of an array

Hence

```
('0' + 11).slice(-2) // '11'
('0' + 4).slice(-2)  // '04'
```

For ease of access, you could of course extract it to a function, or even extend `Number` with it:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(n) {
    return new Array(n).join('0').slice((n || 2) * -1) + this;
}
```

Which will allow you to write:

```
c += deg.pad() + '° '; // "04° "
```

The above function `pad` accepts an argument specifying the length of the desired string. If no such argument is used, it defaults to 2. You could write:

```
deg.pad(4) // "0045"
```

Note the obvious drawback that the value of `n` cannot be higher than 11, as the string of 0's is currently just 10 characters long. This could of course be given a technical solution, but I did not want to introduce complexity in such a simple function. (Should you elect to, see [alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513060/31671) for an excellent approach to that).

Note also that you would not be able to write `2.pad()`. It only works with variables. But then, if it's not a variable, you'll always know beforehand how many digits the number consists of.

Comment: You can write `2..pad()` though :)

Comment: This will cut off leading digits. For example: deg.pad(2); will turn 999 into 99.

Comment: well this will not work on ('0' + 123).slice(-2)

Comment: Also this will not add the leading zero for negative numbers..

Comment: ;\`0${deg}\`.slice(-2);

Comment: It doesn't work with negative numbers `('0' + (-4)).slice(-2) = -4`

Comment: that function doesn't work if `deg` is `57` it returns `057`
`deg.pag(2)`

It should be:
`return new Array(n).join('0' + this).slice((n || 2) * -1);`

Comment: There is a padStart function for this. `'3'.padStart(10, "0");` outputs `0000000003`. `'2424242424'.padStart(10, "0");` outputs `2424242424`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Wrong 122 will become 22

Answer (score 70):

Make a function that you can reuse:

```
function minTwoDigits(n) {
  return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

Then use it in each part of the coordinates:

```
c += minTwoDigits(deg) + "° ";
```

and so on.

Comment: +1. seriously, if you're just dealing with two digits, this is the way to do it; short, simple, effective, easy to read. If you need to think about zero-filling longer numbers, then use one of the other solutions, but if you're just doing two-digit numbers, then this is all you need.

Comment: This is also about 30% faster than @editor's solution. I benched this solution first, then realised Guffa was already there.

Comment: This is def the top answer. saved me a ton

Answer (score 13):

```
if(myNumber.toString().length < 2)
   myNumber= "0"+myNumber;
```

or:

```
return (myNumber.toString().length < 2) ? "0"+myNumber : myNumber;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can always do

```
('0' + deg).slice(-2)
```

If you use it very often, you may extend the object Number

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(n) {
    if (n==undefined)
        n = 2;

    return (new Array(n).join('0') + this).slice(-n);
}

deg.pad(4) // "0045"
```

where you can set any pad size or leave the default 2.

Comment: At this moment top solution is that written by @David Hedlund but I test it and it has a bug. I submitted my fix to him but he didn't accept the review. This is the fix to the solution posted by him

Comment: Yes, This corrects the bug.

Answer (score 11):

You can write a generic function to do this...

```
var numberFormat = function(number, width) {
    return new Array(+width + 1 - (number + '').length).join('0') + number;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c34Gq/).

That way, it's not a problem to deal with any arbitrarily width.

Comment: That helped me a lot ! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is Genaric function for add any number of leading zeros for making any size of numeric string.

```
function add_zero(your_number, length) {
    var num = '' + your_number;
    while (num.length < length) {
        num = '0' + num;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

Hope, this help:

```
Number.prototype.zeroFill= function (n) {
    var isNegative = this < 0;
    var number = isNegative ? -1 * this : this;
    for (var i = number.toString().length; i < n; i++) {
        number = '0' + number;
    }
    return (isNegative ? '-' : '') + number;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a thorough, comprehensive zero-fill function (but why not just call it `.zeroFill()`?), though to be honest, I think it's probably overkill for the two-digit numbers in the question.

Comment: :-) think globally. Who knows, maybe it will be helpful in the future for other tasks!

Comment: indeed, that's why the +1. but also thinking pragmatically to the solve the task at hand with minimum effort too.

Answer (score 1):

I was bored and playing around JSPerf trying to beat the currently selected answer prepending a zero no matter what and using `slice(-2)`. It's a clever approach but the performance gets a lot worse as the string gets longer.

For numbers zero to ten (one and two character strings) I was able to beat by about ten percent, and the fastest approach was much better when dealing with longer strings by using `charAt` so it doesn't have to traverse the whole string.

This follow is not quit as simple as `slice(-2)` but is [86%-89% faster](http://jsperf.com/prepend-zero) when used across mostly 3 digit numbers (3 character strings).

```
var prepended = ( 1 === string.length && string.charAt( 0 ) !== "0" ) ? '0' + string : string;
```

Comment: As it goes, @Guffa's solution is about 30% faster than this on with charAt in. By using a numeric check and a ternary operator, there's only 1 string cast and no char interrogation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#detect').html( toGeo(apX, screenX)  + latT +', '+ toGeo(apY, screenY) + lonT  );

function toGeo(d, max) {
   var c = '';

   var r = d/max * 180;
   var deg = Math.floor(r);
   if(deg < 10) deg = '0' + deg;
   c += deg + "° ";

   r = (r - deg) * 60;
   var min = Math.floor(r);
   if(min < 10) min = '0' + min;
   c += min + "′ ";

   r = (r - min) * 60;
   var sec = Math.floor(r);
   if(sec < 10) sec = '0' + sec;
   c += sec + "″";

   return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single regular expression replace should do it:

```
var stringWithSmallIntegers = "4° 7′ 34″W, 168° 1′ 23″N";

var paddedString = stringWithSmallIntegers.replace(
    /\d+/g,
    function pad(digits) {
        return digits.length === 1 ? '0' + digits : digits;
    });

alert(paddedString);
```

shows the expected output.