# standard trailing zeros in jquery which support cents and string

Tags: jquery, trailing

I use the code to add zero after my values and take help from internet and found this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //var number = 258.20;
     var number = 2;
     var rounded = number.toFixed(2); // rounded = 258.20
     document.write(rounded);
});
```

and added to my project but later I figure out that this code is not working with cents, I checked this code with my test cases and found that it is not working properly. If I use value `0.99` its convert into `0.00` and when I use value `45` its working fine `45.00` but when I use `extra cost is 0.99 cents` its convert into `NaN`. I try to find every where but didn't get succeeds. So is there any way to find the numbers in value and check it, if it is number it should add zeros, if its cents it should work with cents value and if the value is with string it should work also with it.

I found the solution and here it is.

```
        function isAlphaNumeric(str) {
            var code, i, len;
            for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
                code = str.charCodeAt(i);
                if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
                    !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
                    !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

        //var testCases = "extra cost is 0.99 cents";
        //var testCases = 255;
        //var testCases = 0.36;
        //var testCases = 25;
        //var testCases = 1;
        //var testCases = 1000;
        //var testCases = 10000;
        //var testCases = 100000;
        //var testCases = 0.53789;
        var testCases = 0.43789;
        Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
            var n = this,
            c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
            d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
            t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
            s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
            i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
            j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
            return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
        };

        if(isAlphaNumeric(testCases)) {
            document.write((testCases).formatMoney(2, '.', ','));
        } else {
            document.write(testCases);

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513032/less-than-10-add-0-to-number

Answer (score 0):

The `toFixed` method might not always ensure the correct rounding of the conversion results.

For example, `(0.947).toFixed(0)` may produce either '0' or '1', depending on the browser; thus, in Internet Explorer 8 and older versions, `(0.947).toFixed(0)` produces '0' – while in IE9, Firefox or Google Chrome the same conversion produces '1'.

You can use `Math.round` in combination with `toFixed` to correct this:

```
x=0.947;    s0=(Math.round(x)).toFixed(0)           // '1'
x=0.0947;   s1=(Math.round(10*x)/10).toFixed(1)     // '0.1'
x=0.00947;  s2=(Math.round(100*x)/100).toFixed(2)   // '0.01'
x=0.000947; s3=(Math.round(1000*x)/1000).toFixed(3) // '0.001'
```

Comment: not working with string like `extra cost id 0.99 cents`.

Comment: @user3833682: Forgive a nitpick, but "0.99 cents" is less than a penny. That is probably not what you intend when you write that. If you are talking about a value that is just shy of a dollar, the phrase would be "99 cents", *not* "0.99 cents". The reason for my nitpick is that it's important to write clearly and precisely in cases like this that are so easy to misinterpret.

Comment: I solve this problem with other js functions. Thanks