# Digits with leading zero in date and time

Tags: javascript

I found this Javascript script online which refreshes the time every second and displays it. I want the program to display digits with leading zero. Currently it's showing 6/8/2017 - 19:8:54 but I want it to show 06/08/2017 - 19:08:54.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function display_c(){
        var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
        mytime =setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
        var strcount
        var x = new Date()
        var x1=x.getDate() + "/" + x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getYear(); 
        x1 = x1 + " - " + x.getHours( )+ ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + 
        x.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;

        tt=display_c();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [less than 10 add 0 to number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513032/less-than-10-add-0-to-number)

Comment: 30/3/2017 - 19:31:22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var x1 =   ('0' + x.getDate()).slice(-2)      + '/'
         + ('0' + (x.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
         + x.getFullYear()                    + '-'
         + ('0' + x.getHours()).slice(-2)     + ':'
         + ('0' + x.getMinutes()).slice(-2)   + ':' 
         + ('0' + x.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

Comment: I put this in and it seems to not have any output

Comment: That's the way to do it. What are you getting when you do `alert(x1);` ?

Comment: nvm. I accidentally removed a line after this. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: You need to replace only the line with the `var x1 = ....`, not the whole code you pasted - are you aware of that ?

Comment: Replace only this part with my answer: `var x1=x.getDate() + "/" + x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getYear(); 
        x1 = x1 + " - " + x.getHours( )+ ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + 
        x.getSeconds();`