# add zero to each variable having a single number

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a = 1;
var b = 05;
var c = 10;
var d = 14;
var e = 7;
```

I need to add zero to each variable if it is a single number.

Something like:

```
for each([a, b, c, d, e] as el){
if el.length == 1){el = '0' + el;}
}
```

Result should be `01` `05` `10` `14` `07`

Any help?

Comment: Well, they wouldn't be numbers anymore - they'd be strings, such as `"01"`

Comment: @tymeJV, it's ok I need that string to store in a mysql table

Comment: did you even google? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513032/less-than-10-add-0-to-number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [less than 10 add 0 to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513032/less-than-10-add-0-to-number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the values to a string and pad with zero.

```js
var a = 1,
    b = 05,
    c = 10,
    d = 14,
    e = 7;

[a, b, c, d, e] = [a, b, c, d, e].map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, 0));

console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
var e=[1, 12, 3, 4, 23];
var o=[];
e.forEach((el)=>{

if (el/10<1)
{
var t = '0' + el.toString();
o.push(t);
}
else
o.push(el);
})
alert(o);
```